# Set desktop default to Unity 2D remotely?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, unity-2d, remote-desktop, lightdm

Is there a way that I can set the default desktop to Unity 2D without logging out? I need to achieve this remotely as I don't have direct access to the computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to run this command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s ubuntu-2d
```